# generating lowercase Coupon code

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon, coupon-codes

I used

```
Use Auto-Generation
```

Magento coupon code but all coupon codes generated **uppercase** like *F1Z8Z2FPQQYL*

how can I generate the lowercase coupon?!

I found code but I can't understand it, how does it generate the lowercase coupon code!

```
 public function generateCode()
    {
        $format  = $this->getFormat();
        if (!$format) {
            $format = Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_ALPHANUMERIC;
        }
        $length  = max(1, (int) $this->getLength());
        $split   = max(0, (int) $this->getDash());
        $suffix  = $this->getSuffix();
        $prefix  = $this->getPrefix();

        $splitChar = $this->getDelimiter();
        $charset = Mage::helper('salesrule/coupon')->getCharset($format);

        $code = '';
        $charsetSize = count($charset);
        for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
            $char = $charset[mt_rand(0, $charsetSize - 1)];
            if ($split > 0 && ($i % $split) == 0 && $i != 0) {
                $char = $splitChar . $char;
            }
            $code .= $char;
        }

        $code = $prefix . $code . $suffix;
        return $code;
    }
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? the coupon codes are not case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

The alphabet characters come from `app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Coupon/Codegenerator.php`

```
public function generateCode()

{

$alphabet = ($this->getAlphabet() ?     $this->getAlphabet() :     'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789');

$lengthMin = ($this->getLengthMin() ? $this->getLengthMin() : 16);

$lengthMax = ($this->getLengthMax() ? $this->getLengthMax() : 32);

$length = ($this->getLength() ? $this->getLength() : rand($lengthMin, $lengthMax));

$result = '';

$indexMax = strlen($alphabet) - 1;

for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {

$index = rand(0, $indexMax);

$result .= $alphabet{$index};

}

return $result;

}
```

So unless you have a different module with a different implementation of `$this->getAlphabet()` then your coupon codes should have **both** uppercase and lowercase characters.